# how can i run a github react native app in my system?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, github, react-hooks

https://github.com/Lagashettik/QuantityMeasurementApp this is the link of app

I have tried downloading it and then opened it in vs code with command **npm run android**

Comment: Try installing dependencies first before running that command. If you have done that already, try to share the error instead..

Comment: tried npm install and sdk older version from too from Android studio... didn't worked... build process getting failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to clone project from your github link, Just copy that link
   [As shown in image, copy from there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGIjN.png)
2. Then run command ***git clone {your clone link}*** in terminal (where you want to keep your project in that directory)
3. Then after one folder is created, open it in VS code
4. Run ***npm install*** in your project directory terminal
5. Then you can run with ***react-native run-android***
6. You are done

Comment: Tried same steps you mentioned above still build process got failed